# Excel VBA Macro, copy the first value in row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that will copy the value in column A of the same row of the cell I have selected.

So for example, if my spreadsheet looked like:

```
| John | Doe | 123 | 456 | Apples |
```

and the selected cell was the one containing 123, it would copy John. If I selected the 456 cell, it would still copy John. Make sense?

I understand the `Selection.Offset( ,-3).Copy` function (would copy the cell three columns back, same row as current selection) but I'm not starting in the same column every time, so I think I need a more distinct references.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the code below in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event of your relevant sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

' copy the cell in Column "A" of the same row clicked
Range("A" & Target.Row).Copy

End Sub
```